# What bee do I have nesting in my front yard

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Can someone help identify this bee? Its living in a hole between a boulder and a retaining wall. Our tree that is above it is now bleeding sap so I'm worried about the tree. Pest control wont come because they think it's a honeybee but I doubt that's what it is. I don't hear buzzing and one bee leaves at a time. They are not aggressive. The abdomen is black with yellow stripes.

[image: we have bees living behind this huge rock and retaining wall in our front yard][image: they are docile and have fuzzy shoulders with a black abdomen that has yellow stripes]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Biology.SE! Take the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about this site and earn yourself your first badge. Also, can you specify where are you located in the world, what tree is that and the size of the bee?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the bee with regards to the health of your tree.